# Python Selenium Webdriver to open untrusted connections

Tags: python, selenium, https

Can anyone help me opening a secured http (https) page using selenium webdriver in python?

As soon as the page is opened it shows certificate error "Untrusted Connection".

I tried following code but it did not work for me -

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
#profile.accept_untrusted_certs = 'true'

profile.default_preferences["webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer"] = 'false'
profile.update_preferences()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('https://192.168.20.35:8443')
```

-

The selenium webdriver version - 2.35.0

Python Version - 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

This appears when the browser does not accept/trust the certificate of the website. To accept the [certificate](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/psm/help_21/using_certs_help.html) for **Firefox**, you can run this:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
    myprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    myprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```